# Heroku & React Deployment Successful with Application error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

my build and application deployment are successful but my app still will not deploy. I have tried changing the server PORT, updating my dependencies, redeploying, rebuild and recommit. I don't know what to do.

I have tried everything I can possible think of, any help would be greatly appreciated!! **Is there something wrong with my server? Or is it something else? HELP ME!**

my server file:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import open from 'open';

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const PORT = 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

My Heroku logs:

```
2018-02-02T05:19:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-02-02T05:20:22.907775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2018-02-02T05:20:24.372493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-02T05:20:26.106642+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:26.106660+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 prestart /app
2018-02-02T05:20:26.106662+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node ./tools/startMessage.js
2018-02-02T05:20:26.106664+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.101748+00:00 app[web.1]: starting app in dev mode...
2018-02-02T05:20:27.126230+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.126233+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 start /app
2018-02-02T05:20:27.126235+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch test:watch
2018-02-02T05:20:27.126237+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.758657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-02-02T05:20:27.777930+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.777950+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 test:watch /app
2018-02-02T05:20:27.777952+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run test -- --watch
2018-02-02T05:20:27.777954+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.786621+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.786624+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 open:src /app
2018-02-02T05:20:27.786626+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node tools/srcServer.js
2018-02-02T05:20:27.786628+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.813779+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:27.813784+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 lint:watch /app
2018-02-02T05:20:27.813786+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run lint -- --watch
2018-02-02T05:20:27.813788+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:28.134869+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:28.134882+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 test /app
2018-02-02T05:20:28.134885+00:00 app[web.1]: > mocha --reporter spec tools/testSetup.js"src/**/*.test.js" "--watch"
2018-02-02T05:20:28.134887+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:28.207190+00:00 app[web.1]: > esw webpack.config.* src tools "--watch"
2018-02-02T05:20:28.207180+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:28.207185+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 lint /app
2018-02-02T05:20:28.207195+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:28.420239+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:29.434664+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:29.434687+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 prestart /app
2018-02-02T05:20:29.434689+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node ./tools/startMessage.js
2018-02-02T05:20:29.434691+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.374402+00:00 app[web.1]: ✓ Clean (05:20:30)
2018-02-02T05:20:30.374420+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.624534+00:00 app[web.1]:   SignUpPage via React Test Utils
2018-02-02T05:20:30.552948+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.553304+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.457582+00:00 app[web.1]: starting app in dev mode...
2018-02-02T05:20:30.479740+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.479743+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 start /app
2018-02-02T05:20:30.479745+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch test:watch
2018-02-02T05:20:30.479746+00:00 app[web.1]:
    ✓ renders first div842+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.631440+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.634135+00:00 app[web.1]:   First test
    ✓ should pass30.634139+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.634141+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.634142+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:30.634144+00:00 app[web.1]:   2 passing (81ms)
2018-02-02T05:20:30.634146+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.220493+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.220506+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 open:src /app
2018-02-02T05:20:31.220508+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node tools/srcServer.js
2018-02-02T05:20:31.220510+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.239017+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.239022+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 test:watch /app
2018-02-02T05:20:31.239025+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.239024+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run test -- --watch
2018-02-02T05:20:31.254555+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 lint:watch /app
2018-02-02T05:20:31.254557+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run lint -- --watch
2018-02-02T05:20:31.254559+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.254550+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.702985+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.703000+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 test /app
2018-02-02T05:20:31.703002+00:00 app[web.1]: > mocha --reporter spec tools/testSetup.js"src/**/*.test.js" "--watch"
2018-02-02T05:20:31.703004+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.767588+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:31.767592+00:00 app[web.1]: > get_happy@1.0.0 lint /app
2018-02-02T05:20:31.767594+00:00 app[web.1]: > esw webpack.config.* src tools "--watch"
2018-02-02T05:20:31.767596+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:32.060004+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.387707+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack built e6aa51ace7cefd89072d in 5132ms
2018-02-02T05:20:34.389564+00:00 app[web.1]: ✓ Clean (05:20:34)
2018-02-02T05:20:34.389580+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.594360+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.594692+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.651197+00:00 app[web.1]:   SignUpPage via React Test Utils
2018-02-02T05:20:34.658270+00:00 app[web.1]:
    ✓ should pass34.659761+00:00 app[web.1]:
    ✓ renders first div544+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.660412+00:00 app[web.1]:   2 passing (66ms)
2018-02-02T05:20:34.658541+00:00 app[web.1]:   First test
2018-02-02T05:20:34.660524+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.659878+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:34.660221+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-02-02T05:20:39.845456+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack built e6aa51ace7cefd89072d in 6512ms
2018-02-02T05:20:45.480480+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: Nochild processes
2018-02-02T05:20:45.448861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-02-02T05:20:45.556771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2018-02-02T05:21:27.875540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web processfailed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-02-02T05:21:27.875691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-02-02T05:21:28.025829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-02-02T05:21:28.011800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-02-02T05:21:29.827718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=roadtripadventuremap.herokuapp.com request_id=17fd46a1-817b-4501-9312-7bfe7a5a718d fwd="169.234.121.183" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-02T05:21:30.947465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=roadtripadventuremap.herokuapp.com request_id=8a9a2659-55aa-44fc-9514-b0877b09a50a fwd="169.234.121.183" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your project and referring to this read me on proper setup

https://ditrospecta.com/javascript/react/es6/webpack/heroku/2015/08/08/deploying-react-webpack-heroku.html

Looks like your start function is not what you mean to be running on npm start, as it does not start the dist server.
Since heroku attempts to run npm start by default, it starts it as if you were in dev.

I would change "scripts" in package.json to

```
"scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node ./tools/startMessage.js",
    "start-dev": "npm-run-all --parallel open:src lint:watch test:watch",
    "start": "node tools/distServer.js",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist",
    "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test lint build:html",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
    "postbuild": "babel-node tools/distServer.js"
},
```

You will also have to remove the import statements to work on the heroku server so change your distServer.js to

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const open = require('open');

/* eslint-disable no-console */

const PORT = 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Comment: Edited. Using these changes, I could deploy to a test heroku server
https://arcane-wave-68463.herokuapp.com/
Best of luck. looks like a fun project